# Prove: a $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$-polynomial of degree $>1$ is not injective

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, solution-verification

> Show that a polynomial of degree $>1$ is not injective (as  $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$-map).

**My attempt:**

Consider $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$, then the polynomial $f$ is holomorphic in $z_0$. Suppose that $f$ is injective. In particular, $f$ is injective in a neighborhood of $z_0$, implying that $f'(z_0)\ne 0$. Thus $\operatorname{mult}_{z=z_0}f(z)=1$, so that $f(z)=(z-z_0)g(z)$ for $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ holomorphic in $z_0$ and $g(z_0)\ne 0$.

I want to show that $g$ has to be a constant function, because this would imply that $\deg f = 1$, yielding a contradiction. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your argument is overkill. You already seem to have available to you the claim that if "$f(z_{0}) = 0 $ for some $z_{0}$, then $f$ is not injective in a some neighborhood of $z_{0}$. But you know that since $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\geq 2$, $f'$ is a non-constant polynomial and so has a zero by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is a polynomial function, $g$ is a polynomial function too. But $g$ has no zeros. Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, it is a constant function.

Comment: How did you find that $g$ has no zeroes? Isn't it possible that there is some $z_1\ne z_0$ for which $g(z_1)=0$?

Comment: Then you would have $f(z_1)=(z_1-z_0)g(z_1)=0$, which is impossible, since $f(z_0)=0$, $f$ is injective, and $z_0\neq z_1$.

Comment: Of course! I missed that $z_0$ is a zero of $f$. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

It's not restrictive to assume the polynomial is monic. If it has two distinct roots $a$ and $b$, then the function is not injective as $f(a)=0=f(b)$.

Otherwise $f$ has a single root, hence it is of the form $f(z)=(z-a)^n$, where $n>1$ is the degree. Since there are $n$ distinct $n$-th roots of unity, the function is not injective.